Make font size in YAML in R markdown in Rstudio smaller
I wonder how to make the font of "**Citation:** *Doe J. (in press). Journal.*" in YMAL smaller?
```
---
title: 'XYZ''*'
author: '&copy; John Doe'
date: "**Citation:** *Doe J. (in press). Journal.*" # Make this font size smaller
output:
  html_document:
    code_folding: hide
    number_sections: yes
    theme: united
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
    toc_float: yes
    fig_width: 5
    fig_height: 5
  word_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: '3'
toc-title: Table of Contents
---
```


for html you could use inline css: "<span style='font-size: 0.75em;'>**Citation:** *Doe J. (in press). Journal.*</span>"

@Julian, that's amazing! Thanks so much! I highly encourage you to write this as an answer so I can accept and upvote! BTW, can we also change the color of the font to gray and/or add yellow highlight that?

You can use inline css in the YAML header and customize the styling to your preferences:
date: "<span style='font-size: 0.75em; color: gray; background-color: yellow;'>**Citation:** *Doe J. (in press). Journal.*</span>"

